# Add a second website in moderncv banking

Tags: titles, moderncv, cv

I wanted to include 2 websites in my resume which I am making using `moderncv` but it seems it allows only one website. How to show 2 websites in the header (showing the website icon for both)? I am using `moderncv`'s `banking` style.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't know what code to write, hence this question

Comment: No worries! It looks like you got an answer anyway. But what an MWE is supposed to do is provide a basis for anyone who might try to help you. So even, in this case, putting together an MWE with just the one website and then indicating that you somehow want to have two websites would have been helpful, so that anyone who tries to help you doesn't have to go through that process her-/himself.

Comment: Ah ok. Got it! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following solution provides a general approach to adding two homepages and requires the following addition to your [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\homepageA}[1]{\def\@homepageA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\homepageB}[1]{\def\@homepageB{#1}}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}}% <search>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepageA}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepageA}}}%
   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepageB}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepageB}}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

With the aid of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), the `banking` style `\maketitle` macro is patched to insert two homepages. These homepages are specified using `\homepageA` and `\homepageB`, which use a similar interface to the original `\homepage` (which now doesn't get used anymore).

[image]

---

This approach translates directly to the use of emails as well via the following set of instructions:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\emailA}[1]{\def\@emailA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\emailB}[1]{\def\@emailB{#1}}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}}% <search>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@emailA}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@emailA}}}%
   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@emailB}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@emailB}}}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Now two email addresses are specifier via `\emailA` and `\emailB`, respectively:

[image]

Comment: Can the same method be followed for 2 email addresses?

Comment: @pratnala: I've updated my answer to reflect this...

Answer (score 10):

To add an extra hompage there is a much easiers way, like this:

```
\extrainfo{\homepagesymbol\httplink{http://example.com}}
```

Comment: Definitely much simpler! One ought to note though that you are only allowed one `extrainfo{}` command.